# Perform a switch statement within a pandas assign

Tags: python, pandas

I want to have a field in my data that flags the 'focus' rows for later charting them in different ways.  Here's some code that works, and returns the output I'm after:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon', 'Parrot', 'Parrot', 'Lemur'],
    'Max Speed': [380., 370., 24., 26., 19.]}
).assign(Highlight = 'background')
    
df.loc[df.Animal == 'Parrot', 'Highlight'] = 'highlight'
    
print(df)
```

Which returns

[image]

However, it feels like it would be more correct (or at least, more elegant) to create the `Highlight` column in one step during assign (maybe using something like `Highlight = if df.Animal == 'Parrot' then 'highlight' else 'background' end`), rather than a placeholder variable that then gets updated later on.

Is this possible?  Is it the right way of going about the task?

Comment: Try ``df.assign(Highlight=np.where(df.Animal == "Parrot", "highlight", "background"))``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.assign` method can handle equations, per https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html.

I'd suggest that the most flexible and pythonic way to do this would be to just have a list of any animals that receive the highlight tag. Then use a `.apply` and a lambda inside the assign. For example:

```py
highlights = ['Parrot']
df = df.assign(Highlight = df['Animal'].apply(lambda x: 'highlight' if x in highlights else 'background'))
```

This gives:

```py
>>> print(df)

   Animal  Max Speed   Highlight
0  Falcon      380.0  background
1  Falcon      370.0  background
2  Parrot       24.0   highlight
3  Parrot       26.0   highlight
4   Lemur       19.0  background
```